# What can の必要から possibly mean?

Tags: grammar, particle-で, particle-から

From [付（き）合い（つきあい）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BB%98%E5%90%88%E3%81%84/)

つき‐あい〔‐あひ〕【付（き）合い】 の解説
１ 人と交際すること。「彼とは長い―だ」

２ 義理や社交上の必要**から**人と交わること。「―が悪い人」「―酒」

→交際［用法］

Wouldn't で be better here? I think sounds better imo. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

And if the meaning would be:

> "*To interact with people **from/out of** the need of obligation and a social life*"

で would work, right?

It sounds *English* and kind of out of place, I guess.

But my other question how is から used here? In my interpretation it seems as if の必要 is a source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is,  から means *from/out of* and で works but not better.

Here から indicates reason/cause, which で can also express.

[で](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A7/#jn-148951)

> ７ 動作・作用の原因・理由を表す。「受験勉強―暇がない」「君のおかげ―助かった」

[から](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89/#jn-45491)

> ３ 理由・原因・動機・根拠を表す。…のために。…によって。「操作ミス―事故が生じた」

I do not feel any difference in meaning between 必要で/必要から, but the latter sounds more idiomatic. Or taking the above definitions very literally, 必要から is a usage of 動機, which is why で is less natural.